# $\{f \in \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\} : \forall k \in \mathbb N,f(2^k) = f (2^{k+1})\}$ is not countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that the following set is not a countable set using Cantor's diagonal method.
$$B =\{f \in \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\} : \forall k \in \mathbb N,f(2^k) = f (2^{k+1})\}$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: construct a injection from $B$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no control of $f$'s action on the positive powers of 3.  Proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B$ were countable, and enumerate its elements $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ and so on.  Pick any number $m$ that is not a power of two.  The above answer suggests letting $m$ be three, but you can pick any number you'd like, as long as the powers of $m$ (i.e., $m, m^2, m^3,$ etc.) are not equal to any of the powers of two.  Define a function $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that (1) $g(n) = 0$ if $n$ is not a power of $m$ and (2) $g(m^k) = 1 - f_k(m^k)$ for all $k \geq 1$.  Then $g$ is an element of $B$ (why?), but it is not equal to $f_k$ for any $k \geq n$ (why?).